# Customer creation on stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

i am trying with this...

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
   "card" => $token,
   "plan" => "gold",
   "email" => "payinguser@example.com")
);
```

But no luck so far.

Comment: Please provide some more details about the environment in which you're trying all this.

Comment: what do you mean 'no luck'? If you got the token correctly, that's the right syntax to create a customer.

Comment: yes i have token correctly but some error in create customer syntax...

Answer (score 0):

That's right: Now keep the `$customer->id.` Then you can make a charge like so:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => $total, // amount in cents, again
          "currency" => "usd",
          "customer" => $customer->id,
          "description" => "My Charge")
        );
```

Comment: Well the code you have above is correct. Are you getting a token? Do you have the publishable_key and secret_key?

Comment: For starters you have called `Stripe::setApiKey($STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);` before creating the customer, right?